# Use AssemblyInfo.cs VersionNumber as foldername in Post-Build Command Line or any other alternative ways

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version, post-build

I wanna use Version Number stated inside AssemblyInfo.cs as foldername in Post-Build Command Line.. How can I extract out the version number as a variable to set as the folder name? or is there any other alternative ways?

I tried using sed tools and filever but it doesn't seems to work as mention in this post [Determine Assembly Version during a Post Build Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243593/determine-assembly-version-during-a-post-build-event)

Comment: take a look  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139709/how-can-i-retrieve-major-minor-build-revision-number-on-build-events

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this I don't really get what it mean. Can you briefly explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/edit the AfterBuild target in your build file, this build file might be the csproj/vbproj file for your project depending on what you are trying to achieve.  If you add this

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>  
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFiles="C:\build\%(AssemblyVersion.Version)\$(TargetName).dll" />   
  </Target>
```

It will copy the Assembly build by the csproj file in this case to C:\build\version number\myassembly.dll.

Comment: I have AssemblyVersion.Version and it returns 0.0.0.0 (does not match my version set in the Assembly.cs which is 1.0.0) but when I use your AssemblyVersion.Version it returns nothing (empty String) ? However my source file is $(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe