# How to build release in Visual Studio to version subfolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I would like every new version to be automatically compiled into a subfolder whose name would be the version number. Does anyone of you know how to get this effect in a simple way? Maybe some extension or NuGet package that does it? Or pre / post -build events?
I use the "Automatic Versions 1" extension for versioning

Comment: Use some continuous integration tool and there should be tools for achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a post-build event and use xcopy to copy the files. As for the version number, maybe this can help: [How to get the version number in post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486618/how-to-get-version-number-in-post-build-event)

Comment: Thanks, I've done it using post-build event and for creating version subfolder I'm using this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371257/2695941