# Launch NSIS when building with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nsis

I have written a NSIS script for my project, and I would like to automatically create the setup file when I build the project. How can I do this with Visual Studio? Is there a way to pass parameters to the script?
I mean, I would like VS to pass the Assembly Version to the script. Right now, I have to manually edit a line in the script

```
VIProductVersion 1.5.0.1
```

and I sometime forget to update it. Is there a way to automate the process?

Comment: As of today, 10 years later, I'm still only seeing commercial products in this space.

Answer (score 1):

You can create defines and/or execute script instructions by using the `/D` and `/X` [makensis parameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.1.4)

NSIS can also read files with [!searchparse](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.4.13)

Comment: Thanks for the /D and /X parameters, they where exactly what I needed, but how do I make VS output the Assembly version, so that I can pass it to makensis.exe? I was trying to get the version string from the file attributes of the project executable using the Powershell, but maybe there is a simpler method

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here.

Q1. Launch NSIS when building with Visual Studio?

A1. Make a Post-build event that runs makensis on the .nsi file:

```bash
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\NSISInstaller\Installer.nsi"
```

Q2. Pass the Assembly Version to the post build event?

A2. Answered here: [Determine assembly version during a post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243593/determine-assembly-version-during-a-post-build-event)

Combined solution should be:

```bash
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\NSISInstaller\Installer.nsi" /DPRODUCT_VERSION=$(AssemblyVersion)
```