# Create nuget package from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have installed the NuGet.Tools.2013.vsix on my VS2013. And I like create a nuget package from Manager Console, but when I try I get a mensagem:

**The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

I don't know what I do wrong.

Is possible use the Manager Console to create a package, or I need use other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have `nuget.exe` somewhere on `%PATH%`.

***Note:*** We use Jenkins and needed [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to get the %PATH% variable available during the build process.

Edit your `.csproj` file to include a new macro variable for the assembly version number, see [Determine Assembly Version during a Post Build Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371257/371)

```
<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <ItemGroup>
    <VersionNumber Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
    PostBuildMacros;
  </PostBuildEventDependsOn>    
  <PostBuildEvent>echo HELLO, THE ASSEMBLY VERSION IS: @(VersionNumber)</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Use the following post-build script to deploy new packages whenever the assembly version has changed and a new `.nupkg` is required;

```
IF "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (
  CD /D $(ProjectDir)
  IF EXIST $(TargetName).@(VersionNumber).nupkg EXIT
  nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Properties Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)
  nuget push $(TargetName).@(VersionNumber).nupkg -s http://mynugetserver
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but if you are using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio then you don't need to start commands with nuget in that window. I typically use the Package Manager Console for installing/updating packages for my current solution. For example:

```
Install-Package Nunit
```

Usually you create your packages by calling nuget from the normal Windows command line with something like:

```
nuget pack Library.csproj
```

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package for more info.

Comment: Tried that link, but pack Library.nuspec doesn't work. How can we create nuget packages without installing another program and changing the path variable?

Comment: The question is how to nuget pack from NPC.  The answer can't be "Don't use NPC, use Windows CLI"

Answer (score 6):

The NuGet Package Manager Console does not expose any commands to create NuGet packages from within Visual Studio. Neither can you use the nuget.exe commands, as you're not talking to the NuGet Command Line within the PowerShell-enabled console (unless you trick the NuGet PowerShell profile to be aware of the nuget.exe sitting on disk somewhere, by creating an alias for instance).

I did however create a NuGet package for you to install if you want to create the NuSpec files within Visual Studio (including IntelliSense). More info on my blog: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/install-nuspec-with-intellisense

This allows you to more easily author NuGet manifest files, however this still doesn't create the actual package. For that you'll have to fallback onto the nuget.exe command line tool which you can download from https://nuget.org/nuget.exe. Documentation can be found on the [NuGet Docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Nuget package explorer out now that will allow you to create Nuget packages using a nice little GUI. Installs via a ClickOnce deployment.

https://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I was looking for this information.  I combined the information at http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package with information I gleaned from playing with the Package Manager Console.

I created the spec and package from the **Package Manager Console** by doing the following:

```
cd <projectFolder>
../.nuget/nuget spec
```

Replace <projectFolder> with the path to the project file.

That will create a spec in the project folder. (.nuspec file)

Then edit this newly created file as needed.  Some information seems to be pulled in the from the AssemblyInfo file, so you may need to edit that as well.

Then

```
../.nuget/nuget pack <projectFileName.csproj>
```

Replace <projectFileName.csproj> with your project file name.  (I guess it would be .vbproj for a vb project.)