# Is there an indexer available in MSBuild ItemGroups?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, version, post-build-event

I'm using [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371257/974907) to return the built assembly's `@(Version)` as an ItemGroup for use in the post-build event.

However, I want to have Major and Minor separately, as I only want `vMajor.Minor` in the post build. To do this, I'd like to index inside the `Include` attribute.

The following works, but will break if the Major or Minor numbers go over 9 (single digits only):

```
<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Version Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')" />
    <Major Include="@(Version->Substring(0,1))" />
    <Minor Include="@(Version->Substring(2,1))" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
    PostBuildMacros;
  </PostBuildEventDependsOn>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy /y $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)..\Builds\$(TargetName)_v@(Major).@(Minor)$(TargetExt)
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What I'm looking for is something more along the lines of:

```
<Major Include="@(Version->Split('.')[0])" />
<Minor Include="@(Version->Split('.')[1])" />
```

or, only if an indexer is really not possible,

```
<Major Include="@(Targets->Version->Major)" />
<Minor Include="@(Targets->Version->Minor)" />

<Major Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)'->'%(Major)')" />
<Minor Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)'->'%(Minor)')" />

<Major Include="@(Targets->'%(Version.Major)')" />
<Minor Include="@(Targets->'%(Version.Minor)')" />
```

What options, if any, do I have to index an array or otherwise pick apart a version number like `1.0.2838.24877` into `1` and `0`?

### Edit

This now works, by first using a `<PropertyGroup>` I can utilitize `Split('.')[n]` like in [this post](https://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/msbuild-string-manipulation-chaos/), but the `$(Major)` Properties (`$()`) are not available in the Post-Build event (why not? Am I missing something?). This would be more elegant if I could just directly use `$(Major)` in the post-build.

```
<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>@(Targets->'%(Version)')</Version>
    <Major>$(Version.Split('.')[0])</Major>
    <Minor>$(Version.Split('.')[1])</Minor>
    <Build>$(Version.Split('.')[2])</Build>
    <Revision>$(Version.Split('.')[3])</Revision>      
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Version Include="$(Version)" />
    <Major Include="$(Major)" />
    <Minor Include="$(Minor)" />
    <Build Include="$(Build)" />
    <Revision Include="$(Revision)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="Version: @(Version)" />
  <Message Text="Major.Minor.Build.Revision: @(Major).@(Minor).@(Build).@(Revision)" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
    PostBuildMacros;
  </PostBuildEventDependsOn>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy /y $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)..\Builds\$(TargetName)_v@(Major).@(Minor)$(TargetExt)
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Why are ItemGroups `@()` available and PropertyGroups `$()` not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I've come to, with little understanding of what else would be available or how to use indexers within `ItemGroups`.

```
<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>@(Targets->'%(Version)')</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Version Include="$(Version)" />
    <Major Include="$(Version.Split('.')[0])" />
    <Minor Include="$(Version.Split('.')[1])" />
    <Build Include="$(Version.Split('.')[2])" />
    <Revision Include="$(Version.Split('.')[3])" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="Version: @(Version)" />
  <Message Text="Major.Minor.Build.Revision: @(Major).@(Minor).@(Build).@(Revision)" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
    PostBuildMacros;
  </PostBuildEventDependsOn>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy /y $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)..\Builds\$(TargetName)_v@(Major).@(Minor)$(TargetExt)
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I would like to be able to accomplish this without the `<PropertyGroup>` section, if possible.