# Include version number in exe file name in C# Visual Studio desktop application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version, filenames, .net-assembly

I looked everywhere for a solution, and I think that it's impossible to do that !

Can I include the version number (that is in AssemblyInfo.cs) into the .exe filename ? So I don't have anymore to rename the output exe file every release build.

I just posted this question to be sure that in fact, it is impossible to do that.
Otherwise, if someone has a working solution I'll be happy to know it.
Thank you

**EDIT**

I'm not searching how to get the assembly version, which I can find, but I'm looking for how to include that version automatically into my .exe output file name

Comment: What about renaming the exe after it's built?  Post build script?

Comment: @FirstStep : It's not about getting the assembly version, it's about including that assembly version into the file name automatically.

Comment: @StinkyTowel : Can you explane how to do that please ? thank you

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3408709/2779990

Comment: @StinkyTowel : Thank you, but can you explane where to put this script ?

Comment: In your project properties, go to the Build Events menu and add the following to the "Post-Build event command line" text box.  That link I shared has several other solutions as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it !

Thanks to [Stinky Towel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2779990/stinky-towel) for that helpful comment.
I had to modify the script to make it run under my configuration, and as you can see I worked with wmic instead of filever which I couldn't find on Windows 10.
Here is my script that worked fine:

```
`@echo off
set filepath=%1
set filename=%2
set dblslash=%filepath:\=\\%

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%dblslash%'" get version /format:list'
) DO SET "AssemblyVersion=%%I"
ECHO %AssemblyVersion%
move /Y %filepath% %filename%_%AssemblyVersion%.exe`
```