# Compile Name with Current version

Tags: visual-studio

I need to compile my C# .exe with add current Assembly version like

"Some Program v1.2.3.exe"

It is possibile? If not it is possibile use event post compiler for rename the exe?

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/909583/335905

Comment: No, i need change the exe with version included in name during compile of visual studio, not in code program...

Comment: oh, then what you need is to script the build events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857934/include-version-number-in-exe-file-name-in-c-sharp-visual-studio-desktop-applica

Comment: Thanks but how to configure the script in post compile?