# How do I reference a variable at the command line using light.exe in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have read references that seem to suggest the ability to reference a bind or WiX variable at the command line [(this one being the most obvious)](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html).  This would give me the ability to add the Assembly Information to the name of the MSI that gets generated.  For example,

```
light.exe ... -out Installer.!(bind.FileVersion.myExe).msi ...
light.exe ... -out Installer.!(wix.BlahInfo).msi ...
```

There is definitely some validation going on.  If the WixVariable ID name is different between the WXS file and the reference in the light.exe command, I get an error:

```
light.exe : error LGHT0197 : The Windows Installer XML variable !(wix.BlahInfo1) is unknown
```

If I make sure they match, then the error disappears:

```
<WixVariable Id="BlahInfo" Value='!(bind.FileVersion.myExe)'/>
light.exe ... -out Installer.!(wix.BlahInfo).msi ...
```

However, no matter what I try, the resulting MSI file never does a run time variable replacement.  Instead, it just adds the !(...) to the file name.  As an example my last build produced a file with the following name:

```
Installer.!(wix.BlahInfo).msi
```

Is this something that can be done or have I misunderstood the documentation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I reached the same conclusion as Bob.  This wasn't acceptable since it introduced too much variability in builds so I solved it a different way.  I knew that an executable run at the command line could reference a Windows environment variable at runtime.  So all I needed to do was to set an environment variable and reference it and voila:

```
light.exe ... -out Installer.%BLAH_VERSION%.msi
```

To make this happen there was quite a bit that needed to get done.  To start, my version number is coming from the Assembly Info of a Visual Studio project.  The first thing I had to do was make it dynamic so that it created a new one for each build.  Changing the last 2 numbers to a * did that:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.4.*")]
```

The next thing to do was to externalize that number so it could be used elsewhere.  Adding this stanza to the end of the csproj did that:

```
<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <ItemGroup>
    <VersionNumber Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
    PostBuildMacros;
  </PostBuildEventDependsOn>    
  <PostBuildEvent>setx BLAH_VERSION @(VersionNumber)</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[Thanks to this stackoverflow post for help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243593/determine-assembly-version-during-a-post-build-event/19371257#19371257)

Of course to reference it, I would need to find a way to get an already opened command prompt to update its references to an environment variable.  [This proved to be the most difficult, but this stackoverflow post came to the rescue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

So now I have tied it all together using a windows batch script.  Essentially, I build the EXE, test it, make sure it is good, run my batch script and I have an MSI file named after the assembly info version that was generated for me.

Answer (score 1):

Light doesn't support bind-time variable references on the command line.